# mongodb query updateMany : Updating fields in a list of embedded docs for all documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have collection called Store like so:

```
    @Document("Store")
    public class Store implements Persistable<String> {
        
        @Id
        private String storeNum;
        
        private String publicHealthUnit;

        private List<RestrictionTracker> restrictionTracker;
}
```

The embedded doc restrictriction tracker looks like this:

```
public class RestrictionTracker {

    private int dailyCapRunningTotal;

    private int weeklyCapRunningTotal;
}
```

I'm trying to create a scheduled trigger that sets all the values of **dailyCapRunningTotal** field to 0 in every **RestrictionTracker** embedded doc for every single document in **Store** Collection -  every 24 hours starting at 12PM EST (I will configure the cron expression in GMT)

I'm trying to use the following query:

```
collection.updateMany(

 {},

 { $set: {"restrictionTracker.dailyCapRunningTotal":0}}

 );
```

There is a document in the store collection which has a list of RestrictionTrackers with 2 documents in them - that have dailyCapRunningTotal fields set to 30 and 50

when I run the above mentioned query I get the following error:

> uncaught promise rejection: multiple write errors: [{write errors:
> [{Cannot create field 'dailyCapRunningTotal' in element
> {restrictionTracker: [ { dailyCapRunningTotal: 30 }, {
> dailyCapRunningTotal: 50 } ]}}]}, {}]

Seems to me like its trying to create a new field with value 0 instead of replacing the existing values

Not sure what the issue is with the syntax as I'm using the queries provided in the following online manual: https://www.mongodbtutorial.org/mongodb-crud/mongodb-updatemany/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document from your db.

Comment: @AnshumanTripathy did you solve your issue?

Comment: @wak786 this is a json representation of a single document in the Store collection

{
  "storeNum": "71249",
  "publicHealthUnit": "222",
  "restrictionTracker": [
    {
      "dailyCapRunningTotal": 30,
      "weeklyCapRUnningTotal": 15
    },
    {
      "dailyCapRunningTotal": 20,
      "weeklyCapRUnningTotal": 10
    }
  ]
}

All I want to do is to change the values of the dailyCapRunningTotal fields in every embedded doc of every Store doc

Comment: @charlycou not yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a loook to [the positional operator $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/positional-all/).
you can try to use this query

```
collection.updateMany({},{ $set: {"restrictionTracker.$[].dailyCapRunningTotal":0}});
```

Comment: does the positional operator only change the first embedded doc in the list of embedded docs?

I have a document in the Store collection that looks like this:

{
  "storeNum": "71249",
  "publicHealthUnit": "222",
  "restrictionTracker": [
    {
      "dailyCapRunningTotal": 30,
      "weeklyCapRUnningTotal": 15
    },
    {
      "dailyCapRunningTotal": 20,
      "weeklyCapRUnningTotal": 10
    }
  ]
}

and I want to change the value of every dailyCapRunningTotal field in every embedded doc of every Store doc

Comment: it will change all the embedded documents. https://mongoplayground.net/p/mL4fQIc_2uJ

Answer (score 0):

I think @charlycou's answer should have worked. I don't know why it did not work for you.

Adding different version of the query with some comments. Also adding link to mongo playground.

```
db.collection.update(
{},/**filter criteria that matches all documents in collection*/
{
  $set: {
    "restrictionTracker.$[].dailyCapRunningTotal": 0/** `$[]` means all the elements of array will get updated*/
    
  }
},
{
  multi: true/** will update all the documents matching the filter criteria and not only the first document.*/
  
})
```

[MongoPlayGorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JRUexOf6RRd)